# Como realizar test de programa java

Tags: java, test, junit

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reprogramacion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Escaner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("¿Cuantas mezclas vas a necesitar? ");
    int cantMezclas = sc.nextInt();
    while (cantMezclas !=0){
        preparacion();
        cantMezclas--;
    }
    
    }
    //Preparacion de valores seguros
    public static void preparacion(){
        //Valores seguros
        int maxTemp=150;
        //Escaner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("introduce la temperatura del motor ");
        int temp=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduce la cantidad maxima de la mezcla que admita tu motor ");
        int cantMaxMezcla = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Cantidad de esfuerzo ");
        int esfuerzo=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("introduce '1' para motores diesel o '2' para motores gasolina ");
        int tipoCom=sc.nextInt();
        if (tipoCom == 1){
            diesel(cantMaxMezcla, temp, maxTemp, esfuerzo);
        }else if(tipoCom == 2){
            gasolina(cantMaxMezcla, temp, maxTemp, esfuerzo);
        }
    }
    //Motor diesel
    public static void diesel(int cantMaxMezcla, int temp, int maxTemp, int esfuerzo){
        int cantCom;
        double cantMaxCombustible = Math.floor(cantMaxMezcla*0.6);
        double cantMinCombustible = Math.floor(cantMaxMezcla*0.4);
        if (temp > maxTemp){
            System.out.println("la mezcla no se ha realizado para proteger al motor");
        }else{
            if (esfuerzo == 10){
                cantCom =  1000 / temp;
            }else if (esfuerzo > 5){
                cantCom = 1500 / temp;
            }else{
                cantCom = 750 / temp;
            }
            if (cantCom > cantMaxCombustible | cantCom < cantMinCombustible){
                System.out.println("la mezcla no se ha realizado para proteger al motor");
            }else{
                int cantO2 = cantMaxMezcla - cantCom;
                System.out.println("La mezcla realizada es "+cantO2+"ml de Oxigeno y "+cantCom+"ml de combustible ");
            }
        }
    }
    //Motor gasolina
    public static void gasolina(int cantMaxMezcla, int temp, int maxTemp, int esfuerzo){
        int cantCom, cantO2;
        int cantMaxO2 = (int) Math.floor(cantMaxMezcla*0.6);
        int cantMinO2 = (int) Math.floor(cantMaxMezcla*0.4);
        if (temp > maxTemp){
            System.out.println("la mezcla no se ha realizado para proteger al motor");
        }else{
            if (esfuerzo == 10){
                cantO2 =  1000 / temp;
            }else if (esfuerzo > 5){
                cantO2 = 1500 / temp;
            }else{
                cantO2 = 750 / temp;
            }
            if (cantO2 > cantMaxO2 | cantO2 < cantMinO2){
                System.out.println("la mezcla no se ha realizado para proteger al motor");
            }else{
                cantCom = cantMaxMezcla - cantO2;
                System.out.println("La mezcla realizada es "+cantO2+"ml de Oxigeno y "+cantCom+"ml de combustible ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Este de forma muy basica se encarga de simular la centralita de un motor eligiendo la cantidad de combustible y oxigeno para el motor basandose en ciertas condiciones como la temperatura y el esfuerzo.

Me gustaria crear de alguna forma una clase de Test para poder testear el codigo, pero no se como hacerlo ya que los metodos no devuelven valores y en el caso de hacerlo tendrian que devolver 2 valores el oxigeno y la gasolina, entonces me gustaria saber como poder hacer una clase de tests para mi codigo. Muchas gracias de antemano.

PD: he intentado hacerlo con assertequals pero no funciona ya que assert equals solo espera un valor, no dos valores.

Comment: Si, assertEquals espera un valor no dos... pero nadie te impide poner dos assert seguidos vaya. De todas maneras, no necesitas devolver dos valores, puedes crear una clase que tenga como atributos tus dos valores y devuelves un objeto de esa clase, y ya tienes un único objeto para devolver en tus métodos. Java normalmente se utiliza con POO, no tengas miedo a crear objetos y clases propias, es una de las mejores cosas de java!

Comment: Cuando te da error estás imprimiendo mensajes en la consola. Adicionalmente podrías lanzar excepciones con throw. Esto te permitiría probar los métodos usando `assertThrows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, estarías queriendo hacer test unitarios. Así como está armada la solución, es imposible. Lo que podrías validar es qué estás imprimiendo por consola. Acá hay un post con [Junit donde validan la salida de System.out.println](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println).

Ahora bien, si quisieras poder lograr armar test unitarios para poder validar la lógica que tenés implementada, deberías reestructurar bastante lo que tenés hecho. Este tipo de complicaciones se genera comunmente cuando, como bien decís, no estás returnando un valor (es decir el retorno de la función es de tipo `void`). Leer valores ya sea por ingreso de teclado por parte del usuario u obtenidos de cualquier otro lado (un archivo, una base de datos, un servicio externo, etc) dentro de la misma función donde aplicás la lógica para procesarlos, genera un acoplamiento el cuál te va a dificultar el hacer los tests así como también que tu función sea reutilizable. Claro que en este ejemplo sencillo puede ser más complicado de verlo.

En los métodos `diesel`y `gasolina` (más allá de no ser realmente auto descriptivos), en vez de devolver un tipo `void`, podrías usar un tipo `enum` que indique si la mezcla se realizó, si no se hizo. Ahora bien, el tipo `enum` podría quedarte limitado, por lo que podrías crear un objeto propio que indique con qué estado finalizó esa tarea (ya sea de forma exitosa, con algún error y si necesitas agregar algún mensaje que indique más detalles).

El imprimir mensajes por pantalla dentro de la función donde tienes implementada una lógica que resuelve tu problema, es lo que te complica poder realizar test unitarios ya que por un lado estás acoplado la lógica de tu problema junto con el resultado a devolver. Si en vez de realizar la impresión por pantalla, retornaras un valor (por lo general suele convenir devolver objetos por un tema de flexibilidad para mantenimiento de tu código) en donde el mismo te indique qué debes imprimir por pantalla, te sería mucho más sencillo escribir tests

Para dar un ejemplo de lo que me refiero

```
enum Estado {
    MEZCLA_NO_REALZIADA, MEZCLA_REALIZADA
}

class Resultado {
    private Estado estado;
    private String msg;

    public Resultado(Estado estado, String msg) {
        this.estado = estado;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

}

class Motor {
    public Resultado preparar(int cantMaxMezcla, int temp, int maxTemp, int esfuerzo) {
        // lógica necesaria para preparar la mezcla
        if(algunaCondicion) {
            return new Resultado(Estado.MEZCLA_NO_REALZIADA, "motivo de por qué no se realizó");
        } else {
            return new Resultado(Estado.MEZCLA_REALIZADA, "valores usados");
        }
    }
}
```

De esta forma tenés una clase `Motor` con un método `preparar` que recibe parámetros (no importa de donde vienen, ya sea leídos por teclado, de una base de datos o valores fijos que ingresastes desde el mismo código) en la que podés crear un test unitario donde según los valores ingresados, validás el resultado que el método te devuelve.

Si quisiéramos hacer una iteración más, podrías hacer que `Motor` sea una clase abstracta con un método abstracto `preparar` en la que te permitiría desacoplar las distintas lógicas que tendría cada motor de la siguiente forma

```
abstract class Motor {
    public abstract Resultado preparar(int cantMaxMezcla, int temp, int maxTemp, int esfuerzo);
}

class Gasolina extends Motor {

    @Override
    public Resultado preparar(int cantMaxMezcla, int temp, int maxTemp, int esfuerzo) {
        // lógica para preparar la mezcla en motor de gasolina
        if(algunaLogica) {
            return new Resultado(Estado.MEZCLA_NO_REALZIADA, "motivo por el que no se hizo la mezcla");
        } else {
            return new Resultado(Estado.MEZCLA_REALIZADA, "valores de la mezcla");
        }
    }
}

class Diesel extends Motor {

    @Override
    public Resultado preparar(int cantMaxMezcla, int temp, int maxTemp, int esfuerzo) {
        // lógica para preparar la mezcla en motor diesel
        if(algunaLogica) {
            return new Resultado(Estado.MEZCLA_NO_REALZIADA, "motivo por el que no se hizo la mezcla");
        } else {
            return new Resultado(Estado.MEZCLA_REALIZADA, "valores de la mezcla");
        }
    }
}
```

Con esta nueva forma de estructurar el código, tendrías las cosas aún más desacopladas, ya que tus tests podrían validar por un lado la lógica del motor de diesel y por otro el de gasolina, pudiendo así hacerle modificaciones independientes uno de otro. Incluso en el caso de que quisieras agregar un nuevo tipo de motor (no sé mucho de motores, pero supongamos que es válido lo que digo a continuación respecto a motores) como por ejemplo un motor a carbón y otro híbrido que sea eléctrico y a gasolina, sólo quedaría crear nuevas clases que extiendan la clase `Motor` (es decir, la clase padre) y podrías agregar nuevos tests para esas clases que serían independientes de los ya existentes

---

Te recomiendo como lectura https://refactoring.guru/refactoring si no tienes problema con el ingés. Sino, puedes buscar información sobre código limpio (clean code). También sobre paradigma de programación orientada a objetos.

Comment: Hola buenas, muchas gracias por toda la informacion la verdad que es bastante util, he realizado lo que me has comentado que es retornar un enum para poder testearlo ya que testear directamente un "sout" lo veia un poco estupido, asi con un poco de refactorizacion como me has comentado y devolviendo los valores he conseguido lograrlo muchas gracias